# Conditional rendering of a Login form in React

Tags: reactjs, authentication, redux, conditional-rendering

I'm trying to render a Login form only if there is no token in redux store. When I load the page everything works fine and I see the form. After correctly completing the login nothing happens and I have to refresh the page.

How I can update the page?

```
const [isLogged, setIsLogged] = useState(false);
const token = useSelector((state) => state.token.token);

useEffect(() => {
    if (token === null || token === "undefined" || token === "") {
        return setIsLogged(false);
    } else {
        return setIsLogged(true);
    }
}, []);

return (
    <BookList>
        {!isLogged && <Login />}
```

`

Comment: pass `token` in array dependency `useEffect []` and also remove `return` as it is not required

Comment: Need to refresh anyway also with token as dependency

Comment: Please do not edit solution announcements into the question. Accept (i.e. click the "tick" next to it) one of the existing answer, if there are any. You can also create your own answer, and even accept it, if your solution is not yet covered by an existing answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing happens when complete the log in because your component state `isLogged` is still `false`.  The redux store updates but your component does not.

There is no need for `isLogged` to be stored in state.  It is something that can be derived from the state of your redux store.

```
const token = useSelector((state) => state.token.token);

const isLogged = ! (token === null || token === "undefined" || token === "");

return (
    <BookList>
        {!isLogged && <Login />}
```

But you can can shorten your check and just see whether or not `token` is [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) since `""`, `null`, and `undefined` are all [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy).

```
const token = useSelector((state) => state.token.token);

return (
    <BookList>
        {!token && <Login />}
```